# Create some components at once in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to create several components in the same folder.
Is there a way in Angular to do so using one command?

A pseudo-command:

```
ng g c First Component, Second Component, Third Component
```

Comment: Maybe you better to change the architecture of your project. It seems you are going to create too many components, sometimes you can handle these things with few components or even with the component factory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ng generate`](https://angular.io/cli/generate) doesn't support generating multiple components (or any other schematics) at once. However, you can loop in your shell *outside* the Angular CLI; for example, in bash:

```sh
for COMPONENT in first second third; do ng g c "$COMPONENT"; done
```